# how to use the Schauder fixed-point theorem to find it's existence of atleast one positive solution of a 1st order neutral differential equation.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, fixed-point-theorems

how to use the Schauder fixed-point theorem to find it's the existence of at least one positive solution of a 1st order neutral differential equation. Can someone explain in a detailed way???

Comment: when asking questions like this you should give bit more detail on what you know already.

Comment: Do you have an example in mind?

Comment: This is my assignment question, i don't have much idea about fixed point theorems. Can someone please show me how to use this theorem to find existence of positive solution of 1st neutral differential equation. Atleast give me some references to read